# How can I position a DIV regardless of page width?

Tags: css, html, center

I have a large banner on my site, and the banner has rotating images, all inside of a `<div>`. It stretches across the whole page, and the images are large, 2000px wide, so that almost no matter what the screen width, the image will just keep expanding to the left and right.

How do I keep the center of the `<div>` positioned so that everything inside of it lines up with the content of the page (about 1000px), and stays there even when the page width is stretched?

Right now, the left side of the image just sticks to the left side of the page no matter what the width, so the image moves relative to the page content depending on the window's width. Here's the code on the `<div>` now

```
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 2000px;
height: 648px;
margin: 58px auto 0 auto;
```

Thank you!

Comment: It may depend on what else is happening on the page since this div is relatively positioned. More code, please.

Comment: Yes, more code. Also might try `margin:auto;`

Comment: Sorry, it is margin auto on the sides. I was just copying the 'computed style' and forgot to change those. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I can seem to do this when the width exceeds that of the page is by using the CSS3 `calc` function :

```
left: -webkit-calc((2000px - 100%) / -2)
```

This will essentially set the left value to minus half of what is remaining. The `-webkit-` prefix makes this compatible with Chrome. You will have to add the other browser prefixes as necessary if you choose to implement this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
<img style="position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-1000px;"/>
```